# Python apache beam dataflow worker-startup error: Failed to install packages: failed to install SDK: exit status 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Before seeing:

```
RuntimeError: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/beam-temp-andrew_mini_vocab-..../......andrew_mini_vocab' [while running .....]
```

in my apache beam python dataflow job I see this error logged:

```
A setup error was detected in __. Please refer to the worker-startup
log for detailed information. `
```

I've found the worker startup logs and the Payload error is:

```
Failed to install packages: failed to install SDK: exit status 2
```

The error is not specific enough for me to debug. Any insight into what SDK isn't getting loaded? My imports for the job are extremely basic:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
import argparse
import logging
import re
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.pvalue import AsDict
```

Comment: how did you install beam? just via pip?

Comment: I encountered exit status 2 for subprocess, it was resolved by updating pip to version greater than 7, reason being `no-binary` option wasnt supported before that version, which is being used in python sdk of apache beam

Comment: @Andrew Cassidy - did Anuj's answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of `pip` with `pip -V`, and try to update it.

Please comment on the question if this does not help : )

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the setup.py file? I had similar problem, solved it using setup.py file.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.